# Can we access firebase during performance testing of mobile apps using Apache jMeter?

Tags: firebase, jmeter, performance-testing

I was planning to perform a load testing on an ios application which uses firebase for data storage.I have successfully recorded the test plan using Apache jMeter. But when I run the test plan in jMeter, it fails to access the firebase. Is there any way to access firebase during the process of load testing?

I have one field in firebase "last_logged_in_time". When I login with the ios app in iphone, the time gets automatically updated in the firebase . But when i run the test script using jMeter it is not updating.

Answer (score 1):

It is just that you are most probably failing to really login.

Check the response you get after login using Viw Results Tree element.

Usually this is due to a missing :
- cookie manager
- header to correlate
- parameter in request to correlate

Comment: Sir, I have checked the response and the response is success. I have already added the cookie manager and cache manager

Comment: what makes you think it's success, is it because it's green or because the response is the same as when you login manually ?

Comment: It shows green as well as a response token is generated in both case

Comment: yes but what about page content in View Results tree are you sure it's ok?

Comment: I'm not sure about it. But in response I am getting another set of tokens as in the case when I manually login with the iphone device.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see the value updated when you run a JMeter test then the test doesn't do what it is supposed to be doing.

In the majority of cases you won't be able to replay a recorded JMeter test as you might need to pass a dynamic parameter(s) which are used for user identification, tracking, security purposes, etc.

The easiest way to detect whether your application is expecting some form of dynamic parameter is recording your test once again and comparing 2 recorded .jmx scripts. If you see any differences - you will need to **correlate** them. Correlation in JMeter is the process assuming:

1. Extracting dynamic parameter(s) from the previous response(s) using [JMeter Post-Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and storing them into [JMeter Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
2. Replacing recorded "hard-coded" values with the JMeter Variables from step 1 in the next request(s)

---

There is also an alternative way of recording a JMeter test, in this case you won't have to worry about proxies, SSL certificates and handling dynamic parameters - all will be done automatically, check out [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) guide for more details.